# Error validating verification code. Mix of client side and server side issue

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

The issue is arises because my request to get `access_token` is made using different `request_uri`. The problem is, that I don't understand what request URI should be.

`FB.getLoginStatus` is the one that gives me signed request, that in turn I pass to backend and make a request for `access token`. The problem is, that `FB.getLoginStatus` doesn't give a clue what was the original `request_uri` used.

How do I find out the original `request uri`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turned out that passing empty `request_uri` does the job.